# How to properly pass objects into ApplicationListener in libgdx

Tags: java, callback, libgdx

I want to pass objects into my implementation of ApplicationListener, but I keep getting NullPointerExceptions, so I am probably doing something wrong.
I get the exception on the line: `callback.onReady();`

Here is the exception (the line number is wrong, because I have deleted the import statements):

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dewi.jones.game_Implementation.create(game_Implementation.java:56)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:144)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
```

Basically, I want a callback to be triggered at the end on the onCreate method.
Please help
Thanks
Here is my code for the ApplicationListener implementation:

```
 public class game_Implementation implements ApplicationListener {

    ICallbackTest callback;

    public game_Implementation(ICallbackTest callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // initialize stuff
        // call the onReady method at the end of the create method, when
        // everything has been initialized and created
        callback.onReady();
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, this game is ready");
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Here is my desktop game class:

```
public class desktopGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "game";
    cfg.useGL20 = true;
    cfg.width = 480;
    cfg.height = 320;
    ICallbackTest callback = null;
    final game_Implementation gameInstance = new game_Implementation(
            callback);

    callback = new ICallbackTest() {
        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            gameInstance.sayHello();
        }
    };

    LwjglApplication game = new LwjglApplication(gameInstance, cfg);


}
```

}

From the advice given by @Mel Nicholso
Here is my attempted solution:

```
        ICallbackTest callback = null;
    final game_Implementation gameInstance = null;
    callback = new ICallbackTest() {
        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            gameInstance.sayHello();
        }
    };
    gameInstance = new game_Implementation(
            callback);

    LwjglApplication game = new LwjglApplication(gameInstance, cfg);
```

Now I am getting the error message: `The final local variable gameInstance cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment`
Please help, thanks

Comment: Remove the final keyword. You can't re-assign a final variable - and you're doing it when you create the new game_Implementation instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the variable `callback` before you instantiate the game_Implementation, not after.  Switch the order of the two lines.

[edited to add] You need to break the circular reference

```
static class MyGameCallback {
    private MyGame game;
    public void onReady() {
        game.sayHello();
    }
    public void setGame(MyGame game) {
        this.game = game;
    }
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    MyGameCallback mgc = new MyGameCallback();
    MyGame game = new MyGame(mgc);
    mgc.setGame(game);

    game.whateverMakesMeReady();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
How can I do this exactly? I have been trying all sorts of ways, and can't get my head around it.  I have edited my question to include my attempt at your advice
thanks

Comment: I have now added my attempted solution, would really appreciate it if you could tell me a way to successfully do it.  Thanks!!!

Comment: `ICallbackTest callback = new ICallbackTest() {
        @Override
        public void onReady() {
            gameInstance.sayHello();
        }
    };
    final gameInstance = new game_Implementation(callback);` The comment editor ruined the line break, but I hope you can read that.  The trick is to leave out the line that sets things to null and just set the variable to the desired value the first time.

Comment: thanks for your reply
This does not work, because I need the object gameInstance in my onReady() implementation. Also, I need my interface implementation in my game_Implementation constructor :(

Comment: two problems: 1) you can't set something twice and use the keyword `final`  2) you can't make a circular dependency.  See my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create object of game_Implementation without callback.

2) Create object of ICallbackTest using it. (Pass game_Implementation object in ICallbackTest constructor)

3) Use a setter method to pass callback object to game_Implementation
    void setCallback(ICallbackTest a);

4) Pass game_Implementation object to LwjglApplication constructor.